# Multiple rules same action in yacc

Tags: yacc

How to specify multiple rules with same action in yacc?

Example:

```
variable : string {
              cout << $1 << endl; 
           }
         | int { 
              cout << $1 << endl; 
           }
```

Answer (score 9):

This is normally done in yacc by defining an intermediate rule.  For example

```
any_value : string
      | int
      ;
variable  : any_value { 
        cout<<$1<<endl; 
      }
      ;
```

If the values were more closely related than is implied by *string* and *int*, one might use the lexer, e.g., by combining different types of numbers (integer, floating point) as a single token type *number*.

Answer (score 1):

Are these really the *same* action? That is, do `string` and `int` have the same semantic type, or are you relying on different overloads of the `<<` operator?

In the second case (the symbols have different types), the actions are not really the same even though they have the same spelling, and there is no real way to combine them.

In the first case, you could combine the actions by introducing an extra production with right-hand side `string | int`, and then associating the action with the use of the new production. If `string` and `int` are terminals and you really don't need to distinguish between them in the grammar, it might be simpler to just return the same terminal from the scanner.